# Checking site performance on remote vs. locally

Tags: performance

I had read a blog article recently describing how to set the settings on your local host to be a reasonable comparison to a remote host in order to test Drupal configurations and performance issues before pushing code up to the remote.

What settings should I change?
Is it true that the performance should be about the same if the settings are comparable?

Comment: There's nothing special about performance testing a site that's based on Drupal to a site based on anything else. You need to reproduce your production environment 100% for accurate results, and place it under stress that simulates real-world traffic you expect the site to receive. There's nothing Drupal-specific

Answer (score 1):

a: Make your settings the same as your production system.

b: Performance measurements are only meaningful if you compare apples to apples. Your test environment needs to match your production environment - same cpus, same ram, same everything. A dev workstation rarely performs the same way as a web server. It's better to have a duplicate of your production system to use for testing / staging. i.e. if you were using amazon, you'd want second ec2 instance that matches your production system.